# PXDecimalListAttribute converts it to 2 decimals only

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We want to have a static list for decimal values,

but PXDecimalListAttribute converts it to 2 decimals only while I have defined the DAC field with 4 Decimals.

Answer (score 1):

The `PXDecimalListAttribute` has fixed formatting to F2 format( 2 decimals) in the FieldSelecting event of the attribute like below:

```
    public override void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] values = Array.ConvertAll<string, string>(this._AllowedValues, (string a) => decimal.Parse(a, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("F2", sender.Graph.Culture));
        string[] labels = Array.ConvertAll<string, string>(this._AllowedLabels, (string a) => decimal.Parse(a, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("F2", sender.Graph.Culture));
        e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, null, null, this._FieldName, null, new int?(-1), null, values, labels, new bool?(this._ExclusiveValues), null, null);
    }
```

You can create your own version of this attribute like below and set it to 4 decimals:

```
public class PXDecimalListF4Attribute : PXStringListAttribute
{
    public PXDecimalListF4Attribute(string[] allowedValues, string[] allowedLabels) : base(allowedValues, allowedLabels)
    {
        this.IsLocalizable = false;
    }

    public override void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] values = Array.ConvertAll<string, string>(this._AllowedValues, (string a) => decimal.Parse(a, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("F4", sender.Graph.Culture));
        string[] labels = Array.ConvertAll<string, string>(this._AllowedLabels, (string a) => decimal.Parse(a, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("F4", sender.Graph.Culture));
        e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, null, null, this._FieldName, null, new int?(-1), null, values, labels, new bool?(this._ExclusiveValues), null, null);
    }
}
```

}